# Where is the source of datastore-connector-latest.jar? Could I add this as a maven dependency?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, hadoop, google-compute-engine, google-hadoop

I got connectors from https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/datastore-connector
But I'm trying to add the `datastore-connector` (and `bigquery-connector` too) as a dependency in the pom... I don't know if it this is possible. I could not find the right artifact and groupId.

Is there some maven repository that contain the `datastore-connector`?

Furthermore, I am looking for the source of `datastore-connector`, but I didn't find it. By the notes in the `CHANGES.txt`, it seems to be coming from:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop

The source should be in the package `com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.datastore` (`src/main/***/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/datastore/`) but it's not there.

In fact, the source of `bigquery-connector` appears to be on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery) along with its [pom](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/pom.xml), but is the source of `datastore-connector` available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What David says in the other answer is correct. To elaborate more, the connector under the hood uses the [Protocol Buffers SDK](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/downloads), and uses, for example, the [QuerySplitter](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/com/google/api/services/datastore/client/QuerySplitter) to define splits. In the near future, we will be posting more information to [gcp-hadoop-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcp-hadoop-announce) with further guidance regarding the future of the Datastore connector for Hadoop.

You may want to familiarize yourself with other Datastore features that may suit your purposes better, including [Datastore backup to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#backup_and_restore), and [this codelab](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery) walking through an AppEngine-friendly approach to extracting data from Datastore and loading it into BigQuery for analysis. You may notice at the top of that page an announcement of trusted-tester availability for direct backend loading of Datastore backups into BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore-connector source is not available, nor is there a maven repo with the artifact.  Your best option is to create a local raven repo in your source tree as described in [this helpful article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies).